# Javascript Unbounded Regex Literal - need help understanding this

Tags: javascript, regex, jsmin

I'm attempting to utilize wro4j (1.6.2 and 1.6.3-SNAPSHOT) under maven and I've run into a problem with the [jquery.tablesorter.js](http://tablesorter.com/) plugin.

On line 972 (or there about) there is a regex that eclipse and the wro4j JSMin (java port) are not liking.

```
return /\d{1,2}[\/\-]\d{1,2}[\/\-]\d{2,4}/.test(s);
```

So here's the problem.  In Eclipse Indigo, the part '/.test(s);' is showing up as a string (blue highlight). JSMin chokes on it throwing an UnterminatedRegexException.

I've run the C based [JSMin](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html) against the same file with no problem.  What am I missing here?

Doing the following seems to mitigate it but I'm not understanding why this is considered an unterminated regex literal.

```
return /(\d{1,2}[\/\-]\d{1,2}[\/\-]\d{2,4})/.test(s);
```

Comment: It's valid JavaScript, if your tool does not like it, your tool is bad ;)

Comment: wrap it in parenthesis and see if that makes a difference or use `new RegEx()` and see if that helps.

Comment: I contacted the author about this. All other date expressions in tablesorter use ^ and $ except this one (shortDate). As to the veracity of the tools - I have no clue.

Comment: Notepad++ JSMin plug-in chokes on this also, but not if you remove the `{2,4}` or add any other character to the end of the regex.

Comment: JsMin in its latest/current state will NOT fail on `return (/endswith(punctuation)/).test(a)` but will fail on `return /endswith(punctuation)/.test(a)` because it does not understand keywords. It doesn't know that "return" cannot precede a division symbol, so it believes the `/endswith(punctuation)` part is NOT a RegExp but the `/.test(a)` part IS a RegExp. Don't expect a fix for this ever, it would be better to switch away from JsMin. Even the README says "Warning: Do not use this awful, awful code or any other thing like it. / Seriously."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JsMin java port has some known limitations. Unless you have a good reason to continue using JsMin, I would suggest to try googleClosure to handle the js minimization.

Also, when finding this kind of problem, feel free to open an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/issues/list) and probably it will be fixed in next release.

Comment: Hey Alex - Thanks for chiming in! I happened to have stumbled across it and if it is a limitation - great no worries. Thanks for the input!

Comment: I see you also filed this http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/issues/detail?id=660 this afternoon.  Thank you!